# SplunkHttp Appender Error: ERROR Error processing element SplunkHttp ([Appenders: null]): CLASS_NOT_FOUND

Tags: java, splunk, mulesoft, appender

Suddenly from 31/May/2021- we are getting this error

> ERROR Error processing element SplunkHttp ([Appenders: null]): CLASS_NOT_FOUND

We are using log4j2 configuration file for sending logs to Splunk.

Full file below: Intentionally hiding host, port, token, env details.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Configuration status="INFO" name="cloudhub"
    packages="com.mulesoft.ch.logging.appender,com.splunk.logging,org.apache.logging.log4j,com.mule.support">
        <Appenders>
                <SplunkHttp name="SPLUNK-ONPREM" source="app-dev"
                        url="host:port" host="dummy-host"
                        token="token -value" index="main"
                        disableCertificateValidation="true">
                        <PatternLayout pattern="%-5p %d [%t] [event: %X{correlationId}] %c: %m%n"></PatternLayout>
        </SplunkHttp>
        </Appenders>
        <Loggers>
                <AsyncLogger
                        name="org.mule.runtime.core.internal.processor.LoggerMessageProcessor"
                        level="INFO" />
                <AsyncLogger name="com.mulesoft.agent" level="INFO" />
                <AsyncRoot level="INFO">
                        <AppenderRef ref="SPLUNK-ONPREM" />
                </AsyncRoot>
                <AsyncLogger name="com.gigaspaces" level="ERROR" />
                <AsyncLogger name="com.j_spaces" level="ERROR" />
                <AsyncLogger name="com.sun.jini" level="ERROR" />
                <AsyncLogger name="net.jini" level="ERROR" />
                <AsyncLogger name="org.apache" level="WARN" />
                <AsyncLogger name="org.apache.cxf" level="WARN" />
                <AsyncLogger name="org.springframework.beans.factory"
                        level="WARN" />

                <AsyncLogger name="org.mule" level="INFO" />
                <AsyncLogger name="com.mulesoft" level="INFO" />
                <AsyncLogger name="org.jetel" level="WARN" />
                <AsyncLogger name="Tracking" level="WARN" />
                <AsyncLogger name="org.mule" level="INFO" />
                <AsyncLogger name="com.mulesoft" level="INFO" />
                <AsyncLogger name="org.mule.extensions.jms" level="INFO" />
                <AsyncLogger name="org.mule.service.http.impl.service.HttpMessageLogger"
                        level="INFO" />

                <AsyncLogger name="org.mule.extension.salesforce" level="INFO" />
                <AsyncLogger name="org.mule.extension.ftp" level="INFO" />
                <AsyncLogger name="org.mule.extension.sftp" level="INFO" />
                <AsyncLogger name="com.mulesoft.extension.ftps" level="INFO" />
                <AsyncLogger name="org.mule.modules.sap" level="INFO" />
                <AsyncLogger name="com.mulesoft.extension.mq" level="INFO" />
                <AsyncLogger name="com.mulesoft.mq" level="INFO" />
                <AsyncLogger name="org.mule.extension.db" level="INFO" />
                <AsyncLogger name="httpclient.wire" level="DEBUG" />
                <AsyncLogger name="org.mule.transport.email" level="DEBUG" />

        </Loggers>
</Configuration>
```

Comment: What version of Splunk? What has changed in your log4j config from before the error to now? What has changed with your Splunk configuration since before the error to now?

Comment: it is classpath problem, ensure `splunk-library-javalogging-NNN.jar` is added to your classpath. Also, you can try remove `packages="..."` attribute

Comment: If it worked before, something has to has changed. Please provide details of the version of Mule and whatever changes were made.

Comment: Any updates on this? I'm using splunk-library-javalogging:1.6.2 with log4j-core:2.14.1/log4-api:2.14.1